# Can we turn on/off Scroll Lock light by software instructions?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, driver

Is it possible to turn on/off Scroll Lock light by software instructions like *outb* or something else? And if the answer is yes, can we restrict the use of these instructions so that they are only allowed in ring-0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question part one (is it possible?): [ledd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ledd.8.html)

> ledd  is  part  of  the  ledcontrol  package,  which allows you to show
>          arbitrary information on the normally-unused keyboard LEDs. It is fully
>          scriptable,  so  you  can  show  any TRUE/FALSE condition accessible or
>          indicate an arbitrary value. It supports blinking  LEDs  with  priority
>          levels  and  animations.  The  LEDs not used by ledd should function as
>          normal.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But this program uses tty device file to set the LED light, and I'd like to know how the kernel deal with it. :P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SetKeyboardState Win32 API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177674) function